# How many solutions for $(6b)^b\equiv (12b-k)^b\mod p$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Rephrasing my previous question;

If $(6b)^b\equiv (12b-k)^b\mod p$, where $b$ is odd and $p=1+6qb$, and where $p$ and $q$ are prime, are there any solutions for $k$ other than $k\equiv6b\mod p$?

Comment: Where is the $k$ in the equation?

Comment: And why not write $12b-b=11b$?

Comment: @Kurtul,   $$b\equiv0\pmod{p-1}$$ is another set of solutions.  $$k\equiv18b\pmod p $$ where $b$ is even is another set

Comment: Sorry just corrected the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I can offer some advice: if there's no **reason** to think something like this to be true, then you should **expect** there to be eventual counterexamples. In the future, when you have a question like this, I propose that it would be more useful for you (and everyone else) if you explain why you came up with this question and why you expected the answer you did, so that people can try to address the mathematics of the issue, instead of just getting a computer to find counterexamples for you.

---

Let the prime $q=7$ and let $b=3$, so that $p=1+(6\cdot 7\cdot 3)=127$. Then
$$(6\cdot 3)^3\equiv 117 \equiv (7\cdot 3)^3\bmod 127$$
thus demonstrating that $k\equiv 15\bmod 127$ is a solution other than $k\equiv 6b\equiv 18\bmod 127$.

---

Let the prime $q=7$ and let $b=5$, so that $p=1+(6\cdot 7\cdot 5)=211$. Then
$$(6\cdot 5)^5\equiv 185\equiv (4\cdot 5)^5\bmod 211$$
thus demonstrating that $k\equiv 40\bmod 211$ is a solution other than $k\equiv 6b\equiv 30\bmod 211$.

---

Let the prime $q=23$ and let $b=7$, so that $p=1+(6\cdot 23\cdot 7)=967$. Then
$$(6\cdot 7)^7\equiv 196\equiv(20\cdot 7)^7\bmod 967$$
thus demonstrating that $k\equiv 911\bmod 967$ is a solution other than $k\equiv 6b\equiv 42\bmod 967$.

---

Here was the Mathematica code I used (not intended to be even close to exhaustively finding all counterexamples below a given bound, as I said in a comment below; this was just a "first pass", which already turned out to be sufficient):

```
mylist = {{"p", "r", "q", "b"}};
Do[
   Do[p = 1 + 6*Prime[n]*x;
      Do[If[PrimeQ[p] && PowerMod[6, b, p] == PowerMod[r, b, p], 
         AppendTo[mylist, {p, r, Prime[n], b}]],
      {r, 1, Prime[n]}],
  {b, 3, Prime[n], 2}],
{n, 1, 10}];
TableForm[mylist]
```

Comment: So that brings up the question: In the first 2 cases of your answer, the solution is a multiple of $b$. What are the possible forms of solutions?

Comment: @Kurtul: In fact I only even **looked** for solutions of that form, because I was so confident there would be numerous counterexamples and it was easier to look for situations where
$$6^b\equiv (12-r)^b\bmod p$$
since that would guarantee
$$(6b)^b\equiv (12b-rb)^b\bmod p$$
making $rb$ a solution.

Comment: I wonder if there is a solution if we restrict $bq\equiv 1\ mod8$ which makes $q\equivb \mod 8$

Comment: @Kurtul: Before I go to the trouble of running Mathematica for counterexamples again, could you explain what reasons you have for suspecting that restriction has any relevance? That's the only way to actually get to the bottom of this - otherwise we'll go back and forth endlessly, condition and counterexample. What is your thought process? What are your goals?

Comment: Thank you all for your efforts. I am just trying to prove something using the solution of the original question.

Comment: @Kurtul: I'm glad to help. In fact the counterexample I already gave with $q=23$ and $b=7$ has
$$bq=7\cdot 23\equiv (-1)\cdot (-1)\equiv 1\bmod 8$$

Comment: Thanks can you send the mathematica snippet so I can explore other variables?

Comment: @Kurtul: I've added it to my answer.